# in datastage how specify date format in create table for Teradata?

Tags: date, format, teradata, datastage

How I can specify a DATE FORMAT for a date field in `DATASTAGE` in a create table for TERADATA DB?
In a transformer stage I do :

```
ToDate(Convert(' .,-/','',to_synCtrl.REFERENCE_DT),"%yyyy%mm%dd")
```

my table is created with :

```
REFER_DT DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD'
```

and I want to have :

```
REFER_DT DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
```

The connector stage drop and create the target table.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way other than setting `Generate create statement at runtime` to No, then suppling the CREATE TABLE statement text using the `Create statement` property. Or changing system default date FORMAT from `yy/mm/dd` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Is the DDL generated at runtime, or is it hardcoded in the stage?  BTW, as far as I know, that FORMAT in the DDL just controls how a date is displayed, nothing to do with how it's stored.  Any modern tool allows you to control how dates are displayed globally.

Comment: Correct. FORMAT is only used when the database (not the client) is doing a conversion from internal storage form to a character string, or the reverse. If you are loading or querying data and the client binds the value as a DATE data type, then FORMAT has no effect.